# Cannot debug Rust in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, rust

I am trying to debug a Rust program in VS Code, but I get an error:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QapPo.png]

After clicking OK, VS Code opens "settings.json":
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X17Ss.png]

I have these extensions installed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPpZ6.png]

My program is a simple "hello world" app.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately VS Code can't debug Rust out of the box :( But no need to worry, just few steps of configuration will do the work :)

### Steps

1. Install [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) if you are on windows and [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) if on OS X/Linux
2. Click **Debug -> Add Configuration**, a *launch.json* file should open, you need to change the *program* name here manually

   ```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "(Windows) Launch",
                "type": "cppvsdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/foo.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": true
            },
            {
                "name": "(OSX) Launch",
                "type": "lldb",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/foo",
                "args": [],
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            }
        ]
    }
   ```
3. Make sure **Allow setting breakpoints* in any file* is checkend under **File -> Preferences -> Settings**

#### For detailed steps and more you can refer [the article](https://www.forrestthewoods.com/blog/how-to-debug-rust-with-visual-studio-code/) I used to answer this

### Credits- Forrest Smith

Comment: This works! As of 2023-10 for Rust 1.75 on Windows 10 x64 VS Code 1.83. Two different MS/VSCode guides say CodeLLDB should work but I could never get the .json configured right and would get an "unknown error" at runtime, despite "cargo run" working fine. So I Uninstalled CodeLLDB and used only C/C++ v1.18 and using this config above worked--but why wouldn't it auto-generate a working .json for us like CodeLLDB does? And, now I still get an exit code 0xc0000135 and 'externalConsole' is deprecated, ugh onto another search...

Answer (score 11):

From your screenshots, you're on Windows, so here's how to proceed. This assumes you already took care of the basics:

1. VsCode has the recommended [rust-analyzer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer) installed.
2. Your project folder was initialized with `cargo init`. (Your project's folder name must be the same as the name of your package in **Cargo.toml**.)
3. You can `cargo run` from within your project directory and it works.

As indicated by various locations on the 'Net, you need to install another VsCode extension to make it so you can debug. Since you're on Windows, you want to use the [MS C++ DevTools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) for VsCode, instead of the CodeLLDB one.

Next, you need a "launch" configuration setup. Select VsCode's `Run >>> Add Configuration...` menu item. Choose the `C/C++: (Windows) launch` option in the drop-down. You'll now have a *launch.json* file with a single configuration object.

You'll need to change the `program` property to `"${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/${workspaceFolderBasename}.exe"`; this depends on your package name being the same as the project folder's name. (I also changed the `cwd` property to `"${workspaceFolder}"`, though I'm not sure it matters.) To be clearer, here's the configuration I have presently in my `launch.json` file (the `preLaunchTask` property is for later):

```json
{
    "name": "(Windows) Launch",
    "type": "cppvsdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/${workspaceFolderBasename}.exe",
    "preLaunchTask": "rust: cargo build",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "console": "externalTerminal"
}
```

At this point, *as long as you've already built your project at least once*, you can hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and debug.

If you want <kbd>F5</kbd> to ***also*** save your changes and rebuild your project *before* debugging, then you also have to add a build task and configure it to run before debugging starts.

To do that, add the build task by opening the `Show All Commands` box (either <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) and choosing `Tasks: Configure Task`. Select `rust: cargo build`. It'll create a `tasks.json` file next to your `launch.json`; the defaults are all you need. My file looks like this:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "rust: cargo build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, to hook everything up, you just need to manually add the `preLaunchTask` property to your launch configuration with a value equal to the label in your task. E.g. `"preLaunchTask": "rust: cargo build",`, like what I have in my example launch.json up above.

At this point, whenever you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, VsCode will save your work, rebuild your project, then start debugging it.

Comment: When I press Run >>> Add Configuration..., it opens a big settings.json file with no dropdown options. In the bottom there is a thing that says: ```"launch": {
        "configurations": [
        
        ]
    }```, however when I paste the code into the list, it highlights a bunch of the entries as errors. However the error I get when running the code is now different - ```"Could not find the task `rust: cargo build`.```. Adding the second code to launch.json doesnt fix that. Pressing "debug anyway" says configured debug type 'cppvsdbg' is not supported.

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio Code is a general editor, but it can be configured to debug rust code.

**Step 1.**

Assuming that Visual Code, rust and cargo are installed, the first step is to enable the required extensions:

1. rust-analyzer
2. CodeLLDB

These only need to be installed one.

**Step 2**

The second step is to create the rust code. I have a folder called `Rust`, in which I keep the rust code. Changing to that folder, I use `cargo new hello_world` to create a new rust project.

**Step 3**

The third step is to change the folder for the project. There are two plausible options, but only one of them will work.

I changed to my Rust folder, and then I can edit the source code by following `hello_world - src`.

[image]

To debug the code, it is necessary to create a `launch.json` file, using `Run - Add configuration...` However, **the file isn't correct**, with `<your program>` where the correct name should be. This is the wrong approach.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<your program>",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

}

The documentation is a bit thin at this point. The **correct approach** is to pick a different folder, the top level of the project `hello_world`. The `Cargo.toml` file is available.

[image]

Now, when `Run - Add configuration...` is used, and the option of `LLDB` is selected -

[image]

the `Cargo.toml` file can be picked up -

[image]

and then the `Cargo.toml` file is used to correctly build the `launch.json` file -

```
  {
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
     {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug executable 'hello_world'",
        "cargo": {
            "args": [
                "build",
                "--bin=hello_world",
                "--package=hello_world"
            ],
            "filter": {
                "name": "hello_world",
                "kind": "bin"
            }
        },
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'hello_world'",
        "cargo": {
            "args": [
                "test",
                "--no-run",
                "--bin=hello_world",
                "--package=hello_world"
            ],
            "filter": {
                "name": "hello_world",
                "kind": "bin"
            }
        },
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
}
```

Now, both `Run - Start debugging` and `Run - Run without Debugging` both work properly.

Comment: This solution works for VS Code as in 2022.

Comment: Thank you for this.  All the other options dont seem to work for VS Code in 2024